# "patients with X disease" vs "patients of X disease"

Tags: grammar, expressions

It appears that both expressions exist in the internet although "patients with X disease" seems more common than "patients of X disease".

Of note, Google Ngram finds the expression of "patients with" but cannot find that for "patients of".

Are both correct? If yes, what are the differences, if any, between them?

Example 1

[most **patients of Alzheimer's disease** are 65 years and older](https://www.clinicaltrialsarena.com/comment/covid-19-brain-damage-dementia-risk/)

Example 2

[most **patients with Alzheimer's diease** are 65 years and older](https://www.mercy.com/health-care-services/neurology/conditions/alzheimers-disease)

Comment: (1)  is a mistake, perhaps influenced by the fact that 'cases of Covid-19' was in the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

In English, "patient of" refers to the physician.
"Patient with" or "patient suffering" refers to a medical condition.

```
The patient with the perforated abdomen is a patient of Dr. Phibes.

The ape with cerebromegaly is in the care of Dr. Moreau.
```

Answer (score 0):

The modern tendency is to use *people living with X* where *X* is the name of the medical condition as long as we are talking about these people outside the specific context of a medical facility. You are only a patient if you are currently in touch with the medical profession which many people with dementing illnesses are not.